# yum stopped wokring on my ec2 instance

Tags: centos, python, yum, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance on which I was trying to install spark.I removed the required system python version from the system by mistake and nothing relying on python seems to work now including `yum` and other system tools.

I need to fix the broken `python` version in my EC2 Linux(Centos).

Below is the error I get when I try to use yum

```
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I guess, I deleted a required version of python.

Comment: See the answer over at ServerFault: [Reinstalling python on CentOS to be able to use yum](https://serverfault.com/questions/410075/reinstalling-python-on-centos-to-be-able-to-use-yum)

Comment: How is this a duplicate?  The OP clearly states he cannot use yum, as Python is a dependency, which he clearly admits he removed by accident.  Reinstalling yum does not fix the missing python package, as rpm does not handle dependency resolution.  Voting to reopen

Comment: Did my answer help you?  We all haven't heard back from you.  Please let us all know.

Comment: @eyoung100 ,your answer worked.Sorry that i forgot to accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the answer I linked in my comment, I realized that the mirror in that answer no longer exists, so:

1. Browse to the [CentOS Mirror List](https://www.centos.org/download/mirrors/), if the browser is still functional.
2. From your chosen mirror, choose your CentOS Version
3. Follow this path: `/os/x86_64/Packages`.  **Note**: `x86_64` is now the default architecture.  If EC2 is an older version of CentOS this may be replaced by `x86`.
4. Take note of the path created in step 3, and add the appropriate python RPM file to the end.  At the time of this posting, using version 7 as an example, it is `python-2.7.5-68.el7.x86_64.rpm`.
5. Add the path constructed from steps three and four to the `wget` command.  **Example**: `wget http://yum.tamu.edu/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/python-2.7.5-68.el7.x86_64.rpm`
6. Use the Redhat Package Manager to install the downloaded file: `rpm -ivh /path/to/downloaded/file/python-2.7.5-68.el7.x86_64.rpm`
7. For consistency sake: `yum install yum python`

Answer (score 0):

First download python rpm as per your kernel architecture/OS version from following url:

https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7

or

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-testing/python27-python-2.7.13-5.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

Then try installing python  using rpm as:

```
rpm -ivh package-name
```

Then try to install any package using `yum`

Comment: I'm merely stating that the OP might replace the 4 in your reference link as you call it with a 7, since his python symbolic link is pointing to 2.7.  When you do so, you end up with a 404 Error.  I then added that if you follow your example, which isn't really one at all, as python is not kernel or architecture dependent, you end up  on a page full of tarballs, and then I stated the fact that CentOS is very picky about versioning and packages, but terdon beat me to the punchline

Comment: @terdon I understand brother. But eyoung100 is not trying to understand what point I want to make. I have edited my answer as well.

Comment: The first link  in your edit are the tarballs I referred to.  The second is half right.  I remind you again:  If EC2 is not CentOS 7, it is incorrect.  See Step #2 in my answer.  You can't blindly post a link here, as Google readers will click on anything if they think it will remotely solve their issue.  That's why Step 5 is labeled as an example